# how to convert following pcre regex (?<=group\()(.*)(?=\)) to javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this pcre regex script `(?<=group\()(.*)(?=\))` ,how I covert it into javascript regex.

if i have a string group(sum("abc")) then regex should give everything between closing braces of group. like group(sum("abc")) should give me sum("abc")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use lookbehind:

```
group\((.*)(?=\))
```

Comment: but i don't want 'group' word to be included in match

Comment: What's the problem, the data you want is in group #1. If it is not what you want, please edit your question and add some testcases. Lookbehind is not supported by javascript.